# how to make header text bolder using jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I want to make header text bolder but am unable to do please kindly view my code and help me where am getting wrong in code? Is there any other way to do please help me...

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"  data-transition="none" data-theme="none"  class="divimg1">
                <div class="ui-grid-b">

                    <div align="center" class="ui-block-a" style="width:20%" onclick="home()">
                        <div align="center" >
                            <span><img src="../DCBImages/Default_HomeBtn.svg" /></span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div align="center" class="ui-block-b" style="width:60%">

                        <h2 class="fontfamily" >Account Summary</h2>
                        <!-- / This account summary text is not getting bolder ?? -->
                    </div>

                    <div align="center" class="ui-block-c" style="width:20%" onclick="logout()">
                        <div align="center">

                            <span><img src="../DCBImages/Default_LogoutBtn.svg" /></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: <div align="center" class="ui-block-b" style="width:60%">

                        <h2 class="fontfamily" >Account Summary</h2>
                        <!-- / This account summary text is not getting bolder ?? -->
                    </div>

Answer (score 0):

why don't you write like this

```
<h2 class="fontfamily" ><strong>Account Summary</strong></h2>
```

**EDIT:**

Try this

```
<h2 class="fontfamily" style="font-weight:bold !important">Account Summary</h2>
```

Comment: i tried this too ! but it didnt worked .. i guess my jqm.css 1.4.5 is override sumwhere !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work:

```
.fontfamily {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hc745kz3/)**

Comment: its working fyn but shadow is not removed even i had included shadow effects none ...anyway thnks ...!

Comment: @Aniruddh adding text-shadow: none; seems to work in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hc745kz3/2/